# «Мне было тупо не до этого». Значение слова "тупо"

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Что здесь означает слово *тупо*?

> К сожалению, тогда я так и не смог претворить свои планы в жизнь, мне было **тупо не до** этого.

Источник: http://f-seo.ru/lichnoe/blagotvoritelnost-pervaya-lastochka.html

Ответы, пожалуйста, по-русски (конечно, можете добавить английскую версию).

Comment: it means simply

Answer (score 5):

"Тупо" в данном случае означает "просто". Примеры:

- *Блин, после 15 секунды, я тупо упал со стула))))* После 15-й секунды я просто упал со стула (от смеха, от удивления)
- *тупо поржать* - просто посмеяться
- *Я езжу на Porsche Cayenne тупо понты:)* - Я езжу на Porsche Cayenne просто для того, чтобы произвести впечатление на окружающих.
- *тупо сдрейфил* - просто испугался

Слово разговорное и неинтеллектуальное.

Answer (score 3):

Мне было тупо не до этого, то есть "действительно не до этого, безо всякого преувеличения".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) До недавнего времени наречие "тупо" использовалось в значениях, которые предают следующие синонимы:  придурковато, туповато, бестолково, бессмысленно, безропотно, безответно.

Эти значения  связаны с многозначностью прилагательного "тупой":  а) умственно ограниченный,  б) лишённый разумности, осмысленного понимания происходящего (о чувствах, переживаниях и т.п.); в) безропотный, лишённый какой-л. попытки протеста и т.д.

Например:  "Блестящие глаза ее были красны, опухли от слез. Она курила и тупо глядела в пол" (Бунин, Последнее свидание).

2) Но сейчас наречие "тупо" приобрело еще одно, сленговое значение, и это значение, скорее всего,  изначально  означает  "имеющий притупленное (примитивное) восприятие окружающего", но в несколько ином, ИЗМЕНЕННОМ ракурсе.

Наречие приобрело свойство частицы.  Тупо - это "ТОЛЬКО В  ПРЯМОМ (ПРИМИТИВНОМ, ТУПОМ) значении слова, без дополнительной  образности, метафор и гипербол, которые часто сопровождают прямое значение слов.

Answer (score 2):

Это разговорное выражение означает, что причина, по которой планы не были осуществлены, не была чем-то сложным или необычным, а, наоборот, была чрезвычайно проста и неинтересна.

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении `тупо` действительно служит для усиления высказывания:

мне было абсолютно не до этого.
мне было совсем не до этого.
мне было вообще не до этого.

Answer (score 1):

Как тут уже написали, это усиление. Синонимы - просто, совсем, абсолютно, банально. Важно понимать, что это очень разговорное выражение. И его не следует использовать в официальных текстах/речи.

Но в кругу приятелей, которые сами так говорят - возможно. Кроме того, что оно разговорное, оно еще просторечивое. В духе "Я тупо не врубился, че творится, елы-палы.." Его можно использовать для подражания речи простых людей, без претензии на интеллектуальность, или иронично, или если вы хотите придать своему выражению такое просторечивую ауру, скажем так.

Вообще, использование подобных слов сильно зависит от вашего чувства языка и контекста, компании общения. Если не уверены, что оно будет уместно, используйте более стандартные слова. "Мне было **просто** не до этого", например.

Answer (score 0):

Это вводное слово, такое же как, например, `просто`.
Замените одно на другое, или вовсе уберите их из предложения, смысл не изменится.
Так что ответ на ваш вопрос: *оно ничего не означает*.

Comment: Хмм... Может и оно само по себе значения не имеет, ну, я так понял из Вашего ответа что «тупо» усиливает здесь сказанное.

Answer (score 0):

Как печатное использовать **Тупо, Лениво** в таком контексте не следует. Оно может окрашивать действия или имитацию действий (тупо смотрел, уставился, улыбался) и то в редких случаях. "Было не до того** можно усилить другими средствами: **совсем, ну совсем, совершенно, как-то**. **Тупо-** может быть в составе соответствующего прилагательного и составной частью сложных слов: тупоклювый, тупоколосковый, тупоконечный, тупоконический, туполистный, тупоносый, тупоусеченный, тупоголовый, туподум, туполобый, тупоумие.